# Can't push externally changed files to github via PHPStorm

Tags: git, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm 7.1.3.

I have a repo on github. There is an initial commit.

I've used checkout from VCS to create a local copy of repo.

After all this, i changed my files externally (using YII2 .bat file).

Is there any solution that i can use, to find and push this changed files to github repo?

Answer (score 0):

If these files are under the project directory, PhpStorm will recognize them (showed in red for new or blue for changed with default settings).

You can then do the normal commit, just make sure in the dialog that opens your file is selected.

After that commit you can push to github with PhpStorm.

If you run into any trouble you can always use the command line with

```
git add yourfile.bat
git commit -m "a nice message"
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 .bat file put those files in .gitignore .
So all i need was to delete some .gitignore-files and all worked out.